# pandas merge with multiindex columns but single index index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I am using Python 3.8.6 with pandas version 1.2.4

I want to do a self join on previous rows with this dataframe:

```
            bar   
            one  
index                                                                                
0      0.238307 
1      0.610819
```

so i prepare the dataframe before doing a pandas merge

the "left" merge data looks like this:

```
        bar   
        one  
0  0.238307  
1  0.610819
```

the "right" merge data looks like this:

```
        bar   index1
        one         
0  0.238307      1
1  0.610819      2
```

now i try this merge:

```
pd.merge(left, right, left_index=True, right_on=('index1',''), suffixes=('_n','_p'))
```

It throws a **ValueError: len(right_on) must equal the number of levels in the index of "left"**

To me, this makes no sense. What counts is that the values of ('index1,'') are comparable to left.index

What am i missing?

i have also tried the following:
left

```
  index       bar  
              one  
0     0  0.972453 
1     1  0.278209
```

right

```
        bar  index1
        one         
0  0.972453      1
1  0.278209      2
```

merge expression

```
pd.merge(left,right,left_on=('index',''),right_on=('index1',''),suffixes=('_n','_p'))
```

error

```
 raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: ''
```

NB

```
left.loc[:,('index','')]
0    0
1    1
2    2
right.loc[:,('index1','')]
0    1
1    2
2    3
```

So again, some problem i don't understand

Thanks
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it what you expect:

```
>>> pd.merge(dfL, dfR, left_index=True, right_on='index1', suffixes=('_n','_p'))

      bar_n     bar_p index1
        one       one
0  0.610819  0.238307      1
```

From `merge` [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):
*If it is a MultiIndex, the number of keys in the other DataFrame (either the index or a number of columns) must match the number of levels.*

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer.
Yes the result is what i expect, but the expression is not what i expected, given the columns are multi-index.
Seems to reflect poorly on the documentation/design of this aspect of pandas :-(

Answer (score 0):

The answer I discovered is:

```
left=left.set_index(('index',''))
right=right.set_index(('index1',''))
dfJoined=pd.merge(left,right,left_index=True,right_index=True,suffixes=('_n','_p'))
```

produces

```
      bar_n     bar_p     
        one       one
1  1.719833 -0.540152 #different random numbers from question above
```